# df.head(n).itertuples() loop is quite slow

Tags: python, pandas

the following loop is quite slow (takes minutes), although it is calling a function, but the function `getstopscoordinates` is quite simple

```
for row in df_RoadSegments.head(2).itertuples():
    df_RoadSegments["OriginCoordinates"] = df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x: getstopscoordinates(df_Stops, x["RoadSegmentOrigin"]), axis=1)
```

I've tried manual inputs in function `getstopscoordinates` and it works fast, but then in the loop used head(2) just to test in the first two rows, but still takes minutes.

```
def getstopscoordinates(df_stops, stop_id):
    df_stop_id = df_stops.loc[df_stops["stop_id"] == stop_id]
    stop_id_lat = str(df_stop_id["stop_lat"].values[0])
    stop_id_lon = str(df_stop_id["stop_lon"].values[0])
    stop_id_coord = stop_id_lat + "," + stop_id_lon
    return stop_id_coord
```

RoadSegments.csv:

```
RoadSegmentOrigin,RoadSegmentDest,trip_id,planned_duration
AREI2,JD4,107_1_D_1,32
JD4,PNG4,107_1_D_1,55
```

Stops.csv:

```
stop_id,stop_code,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon,zone_id,stop_url
AREI2,AREI2,AREIAS,41.1591084955401,-8.55577748652738,PRT3,http://www.stcp.pt/pt/viajar/paragens/?t=detalhe&paragem=AREI2
JD4,JD4,JOÃO DE DEUS,41.1578666104126,-8.55802717966919,PRT3,http://www.stcp.pt/pt/viajar/paragens/?t=detalhe&paragem=JD4
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the input dataset and the matching expected output.

Comment: for every row in your dataframe you want to reapply that function to every value in your given column?

Comment: I've updated my question with dataset inputs.

Comment: conceptually, you want to look up the coords of a stop?

Comment: @JonSG correct. I want to look at the coordinates and add them to the original dataframe.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for row` loop if row is not used within? Seems like you're just doing the `apply` on the entire dataframe twice.

Comment: also, within each iteration in the `.apply` over `df_RoadSegments`, you iterate over the entirety of `df_stops`: `df_stops.loc[df_stops["stop_id"] == stop_id]`. This is polynomial time. Can you explain in words what you are trying to accomplish, and provide a [mcve]? Almost certainly, you should be using a group-by or some kind of join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading your data, how about reshaping `df_stops` a bit:

```py
df_Stops["lat_long"] = df_Stops[["stop_lat","stop_lon"]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x)), axis=1)
```

Then you can use `merge()` to join the two dataframes

```py
print(df_RoadSegments.merge(
    df_Stops[["stop_id", "lat_long"]],
    left_on=["RoadSegmentOrigin"],
    right_on=["stop_id"],
    how="left"
))
```

Comment: this is so much better! thanks! can I rename the newly created column in `df_RoadSegments` to be `OriginCoordinates` instead of `lat_lon` ?

Comment: sure, you would do that is the two places where you see "lat_long". Just change those to "OriginCoordinates "

Comment: thanks! one last question. when I merge it also adds to the updated dataframe the `stop_id` . Is there a way to not transfer that?
columns after merge `Columns: [RoadSegmentOrigin, RoadSegmentDest, trip_id, planned_duration, stop_id, OriginCoordinates]`

Comment: `.drop(columns=['stop_id'])` or you can rename `stop_id` in df_stops if you like to `RoadSegmentOrigin`